# Ganglia-web how-to add favicon

Tags: ganglia

I cant't add favicon in Ganglia-web

Ganglia-web use dwoo templates, and i not found tag

`<head></head>`

in default index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need add  next string:

```
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

in templates/default/header.tpl

File favicon.ico put in webroot directory